# How to reference an image asset inside the index.html template

Tags: webpack, html-webpack-plugin, webpack-html-loader

Inside my template that exports as `index.html`, I have this line:

```
<meta name="og:image" content="/assets/images/image.jpg">
```

My goal is to have it be exported with the hashed name:

```
<meta name="og:image" content="/assets/images/image.hug2u3g5gx23g.jpg">
```

Instead, it is exported with the original name.

---

My `intex.html` template is loaded as:

```
  new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    template: './app.ejs',
    filename: 'index.html',
    chunksSortMode: (a, b) => scriptsOrder.indexOf(a.names[0]) > scriptsOrder.indexOf(b.names[0]),
    env: {isProd, isWeb, isHybrid}
  })
```

Here's my file loader:

```
{
  test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|eot|svg|ttf|woff(2)?(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$)/,
  use: [
    {loader: 'file-loader', options: {name: '[path][name].[hash].[ext]', context: './src'}},
    {loader: 'image-webpack-loader', options: {}}
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the `ejs -> index.html` template, interpolate the image file like so:

```
<meta name="og:image" content="<%- require('./assets/images/image.jpeg') %>">
```